# Best practices concerning SQLite queries, Sinatra, and erb?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, web-applications, sinatra, erb

I'm building a framework that allows users to install apps to add specific functionalities. The intent is for the user to manage these apps through a small web app. The list of installed apps exists in a sqlite3 database, and I'm using Sinatra to route http requests. I'm using erb templates to design the web pages in question.

My question is, what is the best practice for populating my displayed list of installed apps? Should I make the SQL queries in the Sinatra 'do' block and then pass an array containing the app names over to the erb? Or should I be making the database queries in the erb file itself?

Functionally, I'm sure they are very similar (though if there are functional differences, I'd like to know), but I would like to be following best practices if at all possible :)

Comment: I'm not sure how Sinatra deals with databases, though I'm sure that doing a sql query in the view is a bad idea, even if you are using Sinatra I think you still should follow the MVC way of doing things, so you should create a model to handles all the db queries and the the business logic.

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-sinatra-mvc-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice consists in doing your SQL queries in the `do` block, and passing an object to your template.

It is considered a bad idea to write too much code in the templates, and it can be useful to isolate the fetching logic from the displaying logic if you ever want to use the same template from different routes.

By using Ruby's duck typing, you can make your template very flexible. For instance with Haml:

```
%ul
  - @dataset.each do |row|
    %li= row['name']
```

All you need to do is to provide the template with an `Enumerable` of objects which all respond to `[]`. It can be the result of a database query (most gems return something compatible, I think), or it can be an hard-coded `Array` of `Hash`es for instance.